# VSCode Intellisense support for Cake

Tags: visual-studio-code, cakebuild

I followed the [instructions](https://cakebuild.net/docs/integrations/editors/vscode/intellisense) on the website, but I don't get full cake support.

environment: linux, dotnet (6.0.302), vscode (1.70.0), c# extension (1.25.0), cake extension (2.0.0) - i.e. latest of everything

repro

- dotnet new console --output /tmp/cake
- code /tmp/cake
- install c# extension, cake extension
- reload
- command: "Cake: install to workspace", accept all defaults
- command: "Cake: update intellisense support"
- reload
- open `build.cake`

result:

- no intellisense
- red error squiggles under all cake functions, e.g. `Setup`, `Teardown`, `Task`, etc. - shows "The name 'Teardown' does not exist in the current context"
- works: tasks in command palette
- works: codelens items
- works: snippets

logs:

- no errors in `Cake Workspace`
- no errors in `OmniSharp Log` and no messages related to cake, but it does show this when I open `build.cake`:

  ```
  [warn]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Navigation.FindUsagesService
          No document found. File: /tmp/cake/build.cake.
  [info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
          Could not find document for file /tmp/cake/build.cake
  ```

notes:

- I ran `dotnet tool install --global cake.tool`
- I also uninstalled and reinstalled all the extensions, without success
- I didn't change any of the extension's options in `.vscode/settings.json`
- I also tried this in an `omnisharp.json` file in the workspace root:

  ```json
  {
    "cake": {
      "enabled": true,
      "bakeryPath": "~/.vscode/extensions/cake-build.cake-vscode-2.0.0/Cake.Bakery/tools/Cake.Bakery.exe"
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to some constraints, [OmniSharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn) (the basis for the [VSCode C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp), which also includes support for Cake) currently does not ship the support for Cake in the `net6` versions.

So you have two options here:

- set `"omnisharp.useModernNet": false` in the vscode settings. This will not use the `net6` version of OmniSharp and fall back the mono/.NET Framework versions.
- set `"omnisharp.path": "latest"` in the vscode settings. This will always use the latest beta version of OmniSharp (at the time of writing, this is `1.39.2-beta.4`). OmniSharp does (will?) ship support for Cake in the `net6` versions starting with `1.39.1` (which is currently available for download, but not used in the c# extension for vs code.)

Comment: Looks like omnisharp-vscode [1.25.1-beta1](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.25.1-beta1) includes omnisharp-roslyn 1.39.1. I installed that beta but it doesn't work for me (endless download loop). The c# extension is so frustrating with all its quirks and bugs. Thanks Nils for explaining the situation.